streamlit error: "Did not auto detect external IP" .. how to set .streamlit folder in a different location
I am trying to deploy a basic streamlit app in Azure. This is what I have in my app.py
"""
# My first app
Here's our first attempt at using data to create a table:
"""

import streamlit as st
x = st.slider("Select a value")
st.write(x, "squared is", x * x)

The Azure tenancy I am using is a corporate one that does not have direct access to the internet, and hence, I am using the zip deployment method to deploy the app.
The way this deployment works is that it unpacks the contents of the zip file to a read-only folder and that's what the app service will run from. hence, any attempt to write into that folder fails. This means that  the ".streamlit" folder fails to be created where it should.
I am adding the below startup command in the app service "General Settings"

pip install --no-index --find-links my_downloaded_pip_folder -r requirements.txt && streamlit run app.py --server.port 8000 --server.headless true

I added "--server.headless true" to the above cmd because my server does not have a browser.
Currently, when I deploy, I get the below error message, and there is no '.streamlit' folder created anywhere.

Did not auto detect external IP

and this is what I get in the browser (the url is exposed through reverse proxy)

I tried the same code on my machine and it's working fine, only on the server it's not. in My local, I also couldn't find a .streamlit folder created, but it's working fine.
Is there a way to change where the ".streamlit" folder is created (I can write to any folder outside of that read-only folder)? is there any workaround for this to be resolved.
I cannot use any other deployment method in Azure as zip deployment is the only one allowed at the moment.

I tried deploying the sample streamlit app with zip deployment and it worked successfully by following the steps below:-
For streamlit app to work in Azure Web app, Its mandatory to create your Azure Web app with B1 Plan and select Python 3.10 and above as runtime stack. Also, Disable HTTPS only in the configuration, You can still access your web app with Https and use the startup command below:-


Startup command:-
pip install -r streamlitapppy/requirements.txt && python -m streamlit run streamlitapppy/app.py --server.port 8000 --server.address 0.0.0.0

App settings or Environment variables:-
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT:true
WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE:1


My streamlit app.py:-
import streamlit as st

def main():
    st.title('Squared Value Calculator')

    # Slider for selecting a value
    x = st.slider("Select a value", min_value=0, max_value=100, value=50)

    # Calculate and display squared value
    squared_value = x * x
    st.write(f"{x} squared is {squared_value}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

requirements.txt
streamlit

Azure CLI zip command:-
Reference here
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group vxxxxxxe --name valleywebapp76  --src C:\Users\xxxxsai\streamlitapppy.zip
OR
az webapp deploy --resource-group xxxxxxee --name valleywebapp76 --src-path "C:\Users\xxxxxxsai\streamlitapppy.zip"

Output:-


Advance tool kudu:-


Thank you, I applied all of the above and still didn't work.. turns out it was a reverse proxy issue that was resolved later by another team :|

I see, Glad it was resolved!
